# What is wrong with metrics?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to do Simple classification of road picture ( 1way/2way) with CNN, my dataset is composed of 4k images of class 1 and ~4K of class 2, so normaly the classes are equilibrate, each class is stored in different folder.

But the metrics do some kind of "jump" ? i tryed different size of the input_shape, different optimizer ( 'adam','rmsprop'), batch size ( 10,16,20) and i get the same result... any one know what causes this beavior ?

code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(300, 300,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())  
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy']) 

batch_size = 10
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
#        rescale=1./255,
#        shear_range=0.2,
#        zoom_range=0.2,
#        horizontal_flip=True
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')


test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(featurewise_std_normalization=True,
                              rescale=1./255)


train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/train',  
    target_size=(300, 300),  
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')


validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'data/validation',
    target_size=(300, 300),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=2000 // batch_size,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=800 // batch_size)
```

When i run this code i obtain this result:

```
Epoch 1/50
125/125 [==============================] - 253s 2s/step - loss: 0.8142 - acc: 0.5450 - val_loss: 0.4937 - val_acc: 0.8662
Epoch 2/50
125/125 [==============================] - 254s 2s/step - loss: 0.6748 - acc: 0.5980 - val_loss: 0.5782 - val_acc: 0.7859
Epoch 3/50
125/125 [==============================] - 255s 2s/step - loss: 0.6679 - acc: 0.6580 - val_loss: 0.5068 - val_acc: 0.8562
Epoch 4/50
125/125 [==============================] - 255s 2s/step - loss: 0.6438 - acc: 0.6780 - val_loss: 0.5018 - val_acc: 0.8766
Epoch 5/50
125/125 [==============================] - 257s 2s/step - loss: 0.6427 - acc: 0.7245 - val_loss: 0.3760 - val_acc: 0.9213
Epoch 6/50
125/125 [==============================] - 256s 2s/step - loss: 0.5635 - acc: 0.7435 - val_loss: 0.6140 - val_acc: 0.6398
Epoch 7/50
125/125 [==============================] - 254s 2s/step - loss: 0.6226 - acc: 0.7320 - val_loss: 0.1852 - val_acc: 0.9433
Epoch 8/50
125/125 [==============================] - 252s 2s/step - loss: 0.4858 - acc: 0.7765 - val_loss: 0.1617 - val_acc: 0.9437
Epoch 9/50
125/125 [==============================] - 253s 2s/step - loss: 0.4433 - acc: 0.8120 - val_loss: 0.5577 - val_acc: 0.6788
Epoch 10/50
125/125 [==============================] - 252s 2s/step - loss: 0.4621 - acc: 0.7935 - val_loss: 0.1000 - val_acc: 0.9762
Epoch 11/50
125/125 [==============================] - 254s 2s/step - loss: 0.4572 - acc: 0.8035 - val_loss: 0.3797 - val_acc: 0.8161
Epoch 12/50
125/125 [==============================] - 257s 2s/step - loss: 0.4707 - acc: 0.8105 - val_loss: 0.0903 - val_acc: 0.9761
Epoch 13/50
125/125 [==============================] - 254s 2s/step - loss: 0.4134 - acc: 0.8390 - val_loss: 0.1587 - val_acc: 0.9437
Epoch 14/50
125/125 [==============================] - 252s 2s/step - loss: 0.4023 - acc: 0.8355 - val_loss: 0.1149 - val_acc: 0.9584
Epoch 15/50
125/125 [==============================] - 253s 2s/step - loss: 0.4286 - acc: 0.8255 - val_loss: 0.0897 - val_acc: 0.9700
Epoch 16/50
125/125 [==============================] - 253s 2s/step - loss: 0.4665 - acc: 0.8140 - val_loss: 0.6411 - val_acc: 0.8136
Epoch 17/50
125/125 [==============================] - 252s 2s/step - loss: 0.4010 - acc: 0.8315 - val_loss: 0.1205 - val_acc: 0.9736
Epoch 18/50
125/125 [==============================] - 253s 2s/step - loss: 0.3790 - acc: 0.8550 - val_loss: 0.0993 - val_acc: 0.9613
Epoch 19/50
125/125 [==============================] - 251s 2s/step - loss: 0.3717 - acc: 0.8620 - val_loss: 0.1154 - val_acc: 0.9748
Epoch 20/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.4434 - acc: 0.8405 - val_loss: 0.1251 - val_acc: 0.9537
Epoch 21/50
125/125 [==============================] - 253s 2s/step - loss: 0.4535 - acc: 0.7545 - val_loss: 0.6766 - val_acc: 0.3640
Epoch 22/50
125/125 [==============================] - 252s 2s/step - loss: 0.7482 - acc: 0.7140 - val_loss: 0.4803 - val_acc: 0.7950
Epoch 23/50
125/125 [==============================] - 252s 2s/step - loss: 0.3712 - acc: 0.8585 - val_loss: 0.1056 - val_acc: 0.9685
Epoch 24/50
125/125 [==============================] - 251s 2s/step - loss: 0.3836 - acc: 0.8545 - val_loss: 0.1267 - val_acc: 0.9673
Epoch 25/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3879 - acc: 0.8805 - val_loss: 0.8669 - val_acc: 0.8100
Epoch 26/50
 125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3735 - acc: 0.8825 - val_loss: 0.1472 - val_acc: 0.9685
Epoch 27/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.4577 - acc: 0.8620 - val_loss: 0.3285 - val_acc: 0.8925
Epoch 28/50
125/125 [==============================] - 252s 2s/step - loss: 0.3805 - acc: 0.8875 - val_loss: 0.3930 - val_acc: 0.7821
Epoch 29/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3565 - acc: 0.8930 - val_loss: 0.1087 - val_acc: 0.9647
Epoch 30/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.4680 - acc: 0.8845 - val_loss: 0.1012 - val_acc: 0.9688
Epoch 31/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3293 - acc: 0.9080 - val_loss: 0.0700 - val_acc: 0.9811
Epoch 32/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.4197 - acc: 0.9060 - val_loss: 0.1464 - val_acc: 0.9700
Epoch 33/50
125/125 [==============================] - 251s 2s/step - loss: 0.3656 - acc: 0.9005 - val_loss: 8.8236 - val_acc: 0.4307
Epoch 34/50
125/125 [==============================] - 249s 2s/step - loss: 0.4593 - acc: 0.9015 - val_loss: 4.3916 - val_acc: 0.6826
Epoch 35/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.4824 - acc: 0.8605 - val_loss: 0.0748 - val_acc: 0.9850
Epoch 36/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.4629 - acc: 0.8875 - val_loss: 0.2257 - val_acc: 0.8728
Epoch 37/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3708 - acc: 0.9075 - val_loss: 0.1196 - val_acc: 0.9537
Epoch 38/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.9151 - acc: 0.8605 - val_loss: 0.1266 - val_acc: 0.9559
Epoch 39/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3700 - acc: 0.9035 - val_loss: 0.1038 - val_acc: 0.9812
Epoch 40/50
125/125 [==============================] - 249s 2s/step - loss: 0.5900 - acc: 0.8625 - val_loss: 0.0838 - val_acc: 0.9887
Epoch 41/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.4409 - acc: 0.9065 - val_loss: 0.0828 - val_acc: 0.9773
Epoch 42/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3415 - acc: 0.9115 - val_loss: 0.8084 - val_acc: 0.8788
Epoch 43/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.5181 - acc: 0.8440 - val_loss: 0.0998 - val_acc: 0.9786
Epoch 44/50
125/125 [==============================] - 249s 2s/step - loss: 0.3270 - acc: 0.8970 - val_loss: 0.1155 - val_acc: 0.9625
Epoch 45/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3810 - acc: 0.9125 - val_loss: 0.2881 - val_acc: 0.9484
Epoch 46/50
125/125 [==============================] - 249s 2s/step - loss: 0.3499 - acc: 0.9220 - val_loss: 0.3109 - val_acc: 0.8564
Epoch 47/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3505 - acc: 0.9160 - val_loss: 0.0861 - val_acc: 0.9788
Epoch 48/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3073 - acc: 0.9225 - val_loss: 0.0999 - val_acc: 0.9874
Epoch 49/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.4418 - acc: 0.9000 - val_loss: 0.0301 - val_acc: 0.9925
Epoch 50/50
125/125 [==============================] - 250s 2s/step - loss: 0.3501 - acc: 0.9190 - val_loss: 0.0351 - val_acc: 0.9861
```

it's overfit ? or just the random set parameters position of my loss function ? i will try to found other picture to build new validation dataset ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"each class is stored in different folder"*

So do you mean 1 class is inside 'train' folder,
and another class is inside 'validate' folder?

try setting batch size to 32
and size of training vs validate sets to the ratio of 0.8 vs 0.2

**EDIT**

I found a link that you may refer to:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/187335/validation-error-less-than-training-error

**EDIT**

Try getting more samples.
If there's difficulty getting more samples,
try creating/modifying from the existing samples.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, about the different folder i mean the folder train contains  1way folder 2 way folder and so on,and it is the same idea for validation set. about the split i do that manualy before to do every thinks in my dataset i split it into train and validation set with ratio 0.8 0.2 so normaly it's fine, i will try with batch size 32 and i come back thanks you !! PS: sorry for my bad English like deep learning i'm learning to

Comment: I finaly found the problem thanks you for help, the problem come from train/validation dataset , in the dataset some pictures are closes so the jump come when the batch randomly get different pictures (not closes).